# Bootstrap float navbar items to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Im trying to float navbar items to the right instead of the left 
here is the html i have used `floats` `float-right` class and i think `pull-right` is deprecated so anyone that could help would be appreciated

```
<header class="container-fluid" id="nav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mr-auto" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: im using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create another `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">` for the navbar items you want on the right.
ml-auto will pull your `navbar-nav` to the right where `mr-auto` will pull it to the left.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <style>
    /* Stackoverflow preview fix, please ignore */
    .navbar-nav {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .nav-link {
      padding-right: .5rem !important;
      padding-left: .5rem !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary rounded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link">Left Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Left Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Right Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Right Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: perfect it worked thanks !

Comment: This is great. I'd like to know where to find references to all these css classes? `mr-auto` and `ml-auto`?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal: Those are bootstrap classes. Look in the Bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Add class "**navbar-right**" in `<ul class="navbar-nav ">`

Comment: "navbar-right" class doesn't exists in Bootstrap4